# Standard analyzer, do not treat one character as a punctuation

Tags: lucene, solr

i am indexing some data in which '@' character should be treated like the way it is.
I also need all the features provided by standard Analyzer (eliminating punctuation,trailing s etc), but this removes @ also.
Is there any place where i can specify to treat a character as not a punctuation?Or any filter  that can be used with whitespaceTokenizer for getting such results?
i know that i should write my own analyzer for such requirement, but i don't want to miss if there is something very obvious.

Thanks,
kaka

Comment: I believe that the way to go is writing your own analizer. The standard analyzer is built in

Answer (score 0):

Found [this](http://www.johnandcailin.com/blog/cailin/tokenizing-twitter-posts-lucene) post.Thanks to the author. Use PatternTokenizerFactory with appropriate filters.